# How do I force a specific MTU for only certain TCP ports?

Tags: solaris, mtu, smartos, joyent

**Background**

I have a set of embedded hardware deployed in the field.  These remote machines connect back to my servers at AWS running Ubuntu and I use the `iptables` `mangle` chain to lower the MTU to 500 so these devices are happy.  For reference, this is the `iptables` rule I am using:

```
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 12345 --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -o eth0 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 500
```

**Current Problem**

I'm trying to spin up some servers on the Joyent Cloud using `SmartOS`, but I can't find any information on selectively changing the MTU like I can on Linux (e.g. all info I've found is on changing it *globally*, which is **not** what I want).

How would I do it so that all connections on TCP port 12345 get the MTU I want?

Comment: SmartOS - you mean like the lightweigt HYPERVISOR? Install and route things through a proper firewall or linux - not a hypervisor distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to the Joyent platform so my terminology may not be 100% correct.  I am using one of their `SmartMachine` images, which I understood to be SmartOS running in a zone.  E.g. the intent there is that those images were ready to be configured and used for apps, not additional zones.  Per: http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/jpc2/SmartMachine+Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from Joyent's support team, this appears to not be possible.  The MTU can only be set on the interface level, not via the firewall as one can with Linux.

Note that it is theoretically possible to change the MTU for a socket via the `setsockopt` call (via the `TCP_MAXSEG` option), but there is currently no extension available for node.js to do so.  Other app platforms should use the `setsockopt` call.